# ARKit: Tracking VisonCoreML detected object

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, coreml

I'm new to iOS and I am currently refactoring a code I got from a tutorial on VisionCoreML and ARKit that adds a node to the detected object.

currently, if the I move the object the node does not move and follow the object. I can see from Apple's sample code for [Recognizing Objects in Live Capture](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/recognizing_objects_in_live_capture) they use layers and repositions this each time Vision detects the object at a new position which is what I was hoping to replicate with an ARObject.

Is there a way I can achieve this with ARKit?

Any help around this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

**EDIT: Working code with solution**

```
@IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
private var viewportSize: CGSize!
private var previousAnchor: ARAnchor?
private var trackingNode: SCNNode!
lazy var objectDetectionRequest: VNCoreMLRequest = {
    do {
        let model = try VNCoreMLModel(for: yolov5s(configuration: MLModelConfiguration()).model)
        let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { [weak self] request, error in
            self?.processDetections(for: request, error: error)
        }
        return request
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to load Vision ML model.")
    }
}()

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, willRenderScene scene: SCNScene, atTime time: TimeInterval) {
    guard let capturedImage = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.capturedImage
    else { return }
    
    let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: capturedImage, orientation: .leftMirrored, options: [:])
    
    do {
        try imageRequestHandler.perform([objectDetectionRequest])
    } catch {
        print("Failed to perform image request.")
    }
}

func processDetections(for request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
    guard error == nil else {
        print("Object detection error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
    
    guard let results = request.results else { return }
    
    for observation in results where observation is VNRecognizedObjectObservation {
        
        let objectObservation = observation as! VNRecognizedObjectObservation
        let topLabelObservation = objectObservation.labels.first
        print(topLabelObservation!.identifier + " " + "\(Int(topLabelObservation!.confidence * 100))%")
        guard recognisedObject(topLabelObservation!.identifier) && topLabelObservation!.confidence > 0.9
            else { continue }

        let rect = VNImageRectForNormalizedRect(
            objectObservation.boundingBox,
            Int(self.sceneView.bounds.width),
            Int(self.sceneView.bounds.height))
        
        let midPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
        
        let raycastQuery = self.sceneView.raycastQuery(from: midPoint,
                                                  allowing: .estimatedPlane,
                                                  alignment: .any)
        let raycastArray = self.sceneView.session.raycast(raycastQuery!)
        guard let raycastResult = raycastArray.first else { return }
        
        let position = SCNVector3(raycastResult.worldTransform.columns.3.x,
                                raycastResult.worldTransform.columns.3.y,
                                raycastResult.worldTransform.columns.3.z)
        
        if let _ = trackingNode {
            trackingNode!.worldPosition = position
        } else {
            trackingNode = createNode()
            trackingNode!.worldPosition = position
            self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(trackingNode!)
        }
    }
}

private func recognisedObject(_ identifier: String) -> Bool {
    return identifier == "remote" || identifier == "mouse"
}

private func createNode() -> SCNNode {
    let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 0.01))
    sphereNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.purple
    
    return sphereNode
}

private func loadSession() {
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.planeDetection = []
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sceneView.delegate = self
    viewportSize = sceneView.frame.size
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    loadSession()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    sceneView.session.pause()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, the technologies you're using here cannot do that out of the box. YOLO (and any other object detection model you swapped out for it) have no built in concept of tracking the same object in a video. They look for objects in a 2D bitmap, and return 2D bounding boxes for them. As either the camera or object moves, and you pass in the next `capturedImage` buffer, it will give you a new bounding box in the correct position, but it has no way of knowing whether or not it's the same *instance* of the object detected in a previous frame.

To make this work, you'll need to do some post processing of those Vision results to determine whether or not it's the same object, and if so, manually move the anchor/mesh to match the new position.  If you're confident there should only be one object in view at any given time, then it's pretty straightforward. If there will be multiple objects, you're venturing into complex (but still achievable) territory.

You could try to incorporate [Vision Tracking](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/tracking_multiple_objects_or_rectangles_in_video), which might work though would depend on the nature and behavior of the tracked object.

Also, `sceneView.hitTest()` is deprecated. You should probably port that over to use [ARSession.raycast()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession/3132065-raycast)

Comment: Thanks @Chris
 
I have replaced the use of sceneView.hitTest() with raycast() which has helped with the node’s positioning. 
 
Re: your point on tracking and moving the Anchor, that is pretty much what I thought, and in hindsight, I really should have made my intentions clear Sorry for not reviewing my question properly. And yes, initially I just want to track the 1 object.
 
The method ```resetScene()``` tries to remove any existing node and anchor and replace it with a new one based on the object's position but this does not work very well. Is there anything changes you can suggest?

Comment: I'd recommend starting off with an approach where your store a reference to the current `sphereNode`, the first one you place.  Then when you get a new rectangle from your YOLO detection, you cast a new ray to that center position, and then move the existing `sphereNode` by changing `node.simdPosition` to the newly detected 3D point. There is no need to reset the scene between detections, in fact that seems counterproductive!